# Does anyone know where I can find the code for the carousel.us JavaScript 3D Carousel? Developer's site is down

Tags: javascript, 3d, carousel

Does anyone know where I can find the code for the carousel.us JavaScript 3D Carousel? Developer's site (http://www.piksite.com/carousel.us/) is down.  I see it referenced all over in articles and tutorials but so far haven't been able to find the actual code to download except from that site which is just ads now.

Client wants that specific thing and it doesn't make sense to code it from scratch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

found it.
http://sevilla.gov.co/ajax-scripts/carousel.us.zip

Answer (score 0):

checkout this page http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm